# XLSO & MM "The group data for the material is locked by" when creating courses

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm creating a courses via ABAP Code and for this to work I need to set all the necessary items like:

Abbreviation
Course Title
Sales Info
Begin Date
End Date
Status
Parent Object
Participation
Capacity
After all this I make the course persistent and I fill in the custom info like:

Delivery Method
Material Group
Owner
Schedule
I do all this by importing a file and looping it, with this I'm creating a lot of course types without any time in between.

That is probably while I'm locking my recently created material and receiving the error:

**The group data for the material "material_number_here' is locked by "my_own_user". -> Message Class M3 Message 022.**

I hope you understand my problem and difficulty but I have no clue on how to fix this problem. It does not always occur it happens at random on random records.

Thanks a 1000 times if anyone can help me with this.

Kr,

Vincent

Comment: Are you using a BDC or a BAPI to create the individual materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on my own, please refer to: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3410951

Kr,
Vince